# errbot does not return "Hello World" when I type !hello

Tags: python, errbot

Also when I type !status, Helloworld is not in the list as A (Active).  I do not think it is reading my plugin.  Any suggestions?

```
# code for helloworldld.py

from errbot import BotPlugin, botcmd

class HelloWorld(BotPlugin):
"""Example 'Hello, world!' plugin for Errbot"""


@botcmd
def hello(self, msg, args):
    """Say hello to the world"""
    return "Hello, world!"
```

```
# code for helloworld.plug
[Core]
Name = HelloWorld
Module = helloworld

[Python]
Version = 2+

[Documentation]
Description = Example "Hello, world!" plugin
```

Comment: I don't know about errbot, but is the file name really `helloworldld.py` with two `ld`?

Comment: Your `def hello` method is not indented correctly, it's not part of the class. Is that the same in your source file or just here in your question?

Comment: The file name is helloworld.py  I don't know how I added an extra ld.  Also, @botcmd
def hello(self, msg, args):  is indented under class, so that is not the issue.  It does not appear to be reading my plugin file and I do not know why.  I have the directory listed in the config file. IN config file BOT_EXTRA_PLUGIN_DIR = '/Data/Codefiles/vagrant/HelloWorld'

Comment: Can you try to `git clone https://github.com/errbotio/err-helloworld.git` in /Data/Codefiles/vagrant/ ? If it doesn't work, be sure that errbot can access this directory. Does the log says anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Module name should match python file name. Please check BOT_EXTRA_PLUGIN_DIR = r'/plugins' config it's by default uses plugin directory. Use !plugin_reload  command to validate. It should list your plugin HelloWorld.